# Write a 301 rewrite rule in htaccess to work around malformed links that are too deep

Tags: regex, .htaccess

There are malformed links pointing to my site that look like this:

```
www.example.com/dir1/index.php/dir1/index.php
www.example.com/dir2/page.php/dir1/index.php
www.example.com/dir1/page.php/dir2/index.php
```

etc. So what I am trying to do is to write a rule that will look for ".php" twice and if there's a second instance of it, and the first one has a "/" after it (to protect someone coming to www.example.com/index.php?source=chorizon.com/index.php), remove the first and everything before it. This doesn't seem to match those links:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php/(.*).php(.*) http://www.example.com/$2.php [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: That rule is working fine. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in [the .htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), are you sure that the rule is being reached? Do you have other rules above that might be matching and have the [`L` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)?

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

[image: htaccess sample]